# Validate single record on continuous form

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

So I have a form and a table called Variables.  The table is simply the fields VarID, VarDescription, and VarValue.  It's only three items that are all network locations of things.  The VarValue is the only thing that can be changed through the form, and thus it is the only thing validated.  I validate those records on the form with the Before Update Event in the control by using logic such as:

```
    If Me.VarID = 1 Then
        If Me.Tex like "*:\* Then....
        End If
        If GetAttr(Me.Tex) = vbDirectory Then
        End
    End If

    If Me.VarID = 2 Then
        If Me.Tex like "*:\* Then....
        End If
        If GetAttr(Me.Tex) = vbNormal Or GetAttr(Me.Tex) = vbArchive Then
        End If
    End If
```

This all works great.  However my issue comes in when multiple locations become invalid at once.  I get stuck in one cell because the other VarValue's are invalid as well.  How can I validate only the cell I have changed?  I tried playing around with various Dirty and Focus events/methods, but those seem to be form specific, not cell specific.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `Before Update` event validation to the control instead of the Form?

Comment: I am checking the before update event in the control.  Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I have edited my comment to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to just be a reference issue as I am looking on the database on two completely separate networks.  The original uses all Office 16.0 libraries whereas the instance I was having the issue with was using Office 15.0 libraries.  I played around with the original and it works fine, even if all the locations become bad at the same time.